# Incompatibilities between safe bool idiom and explicit operator bool

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, safe-bool-idiom

I'm thinking of replacing all the instances of safe bool idiom by `explicit operator bool` in code which already uses C++11 features (so the fact that older compilers don't recognized explicit conversion operators will not matter), so I'd like to know if it can cause some subtle problems.

Thus, what are *all* the possible incompatibilities (even the most minute ones) that can be caused by switching from old and dull safe bool idiom to new and shiny `explicit operator bool`?

EDIT: I know that switching is a good idea anyway, for the latter is a language feature, well-understood by the compiler, so it'll work no worse than what's in fact just a hack. I simply want to know the possible differences.

Answer (score 4):

If you've used safe-bool conversion incorrectly in your code, only then `explicit operator bool` be incompatible, as it wouldn't allow you to do things incorrectly that easily. Otherwise, it should be just fine without any problem. In fact, even if there is problem, you should still switch to `explicit operator bool`, because if you do so, then you could identify the problem in the usage of the safe-bool conversion.

According to [this article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool2.html), some compilers emit inefficient instructions for safe-bool implementation using member function pointer,

> When people started using this idiom, it was discovered that there was an efficiency penalty on some compilers — the member function pointer caused a compiler headache resulting in slower execution when the address was fetched. Although the difference is marginal, the current practice is typically to use a member data pointer instead of a member function pointer.

Comment: Of course you're right. But there's a reason I tagged this with `language-lawyer`. I'd like pure facts that follow from the standard itself, not an advice on good practices. Gotta clarify that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Fanael: The Standards, C++03 and C++11 both, do not talk about safe-bool idiom, so it is not possible to quote from it to support what I said. All I'm implied is that C++11 has introduced `explicit operator bool` for reason(s), and one of the reasons, I think, is `explicit operator bool` is **safer** than the so-called safe-bool idiom.

Comment: But the standard talks about the things used to implement the safe-bool idiom. So, while the standard says naught about that idiom itself, its exact guarantees are pretty much implied by the document.

Comment: @Fanael: I added something to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the biggest difference, assuming your code is free of bugs (I know, not a safe assumption), will be that in some cases, you may want an implicit conversion to exactly `bool`. An `explicit` conversion function will not match.

```
struct S1
{
    operator S1*() { return 0; } /* I know, not the best possible type */
} s1;

struct S2
{
    explicit operator bool() { return false; }
} s2;

void f()
{
    bool b1 = s1; /* okay */
    bool b2 = s2; /* not okay */
}
```

Comment: I had already noted that the pointer type I used isn't the best possible type, it serves fine as an example because the differences between this and a correct implementation are irrelevant to my answer, and this is more readable.