# Emulating explicit cast in C++03

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

I'm working on a legacy library that needs to be backwards compatible with C++03, but is also forward compatible to take advantage of C++11 features like move semantics and explicit casting.

So, is it possible to emulate explicit casting in C++03?  I know obviously about the explicit bool (or "safe" bool) idiom - but that's only for casting to a boolean type.  Is it possible to emulate a general explicit cast operator in C++03?

I checked around, and found a discussion about this in a book called "[Imperfect C++ : Practical Solutions for Real-Life Programming](http://synesis.com.au/publishing/imperfect/cpp/)".

In this book, they discuss some ideas about emulating an explicit cast in C++03 (the book was written before C++11).  Ultimately, they recommend creating an `explicit_cast<T>` template.  However, I don't like that solution because I want users to simply be able to use `static_cast<T>`, which works fine in C++11.

So, another solution was to force the compiler to do *two* conversions, which will disallow implicit conversions.  An example of that would be something like:

```
class int_cast
{
    public:

    int_cast(const int& v) : m_value(v)
    { }

    operator int() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    private:

    int m_value;
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        x = 10;
    }

    operator int_cast() const
    {
        return int_cast(x);
    }

    int x;
};
```

Here, a `Foo` should be *explicitly* convertible to `int`, but not implicitly.  (This code is lifted almost verbatim from *Imperfect C++*, except in their example they are converting a custom `Time` object to a `std::tm`.

However, this doesn't actually work, at least not using GCC 4.7.2:

```
Foo f;
int x = static_cast<int>(f);
```

This results in :

```
test3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test3.cpp:44:28: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘Foo’ to type ‘int’
```

So I guess "Imperfect C++" is wrong here.  The compiler wasn't able to convert a `Foo` to an `int`, even with an explicit cast.  (Maybe this worked on older compilers?) So, is there anyway to emulate this in C++03 (without using a custom cast operator)?

Comment: "legacy library that needs to be backwards compatible with C++03" wait what ? What exactly is the language used for this library ? Keep in mind that `gcc 4.7.2` offers an incomplete implementation of the C++11 language and there are breaking changes between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: I'm talking about using `#ifdef`s so it can compile with C++03 and C++11

Comment: How is this ever supposed to work? Should the compiler try every pair of conversions `Foo -> X` and `X ->int` known to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Imperfect C++" is right, *because* it uses a custom "keyword" - actually a function name masquerading as a keyword (not unlike eg.: Tribool's `indeterminate`). If you try to `static_cast` you crash against the limitation that the language can only accept conversion chains that involve up to one user-defined type, whereas you have two conversions - from "Foo" to "int_cast" and from there to `int`.

If you want specifically to be able to `static_cast` then you'll probably have to hack something with macros to supersede normal `static_cast`... and accept to live in Undefined Behaviour Land. My preferred choice is to actually [work in the inverse direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193766/isset-or-operator-void-or-explicit-opertor-bool-or-something-else/20100483#20100483): simply use `explicit_cast` and use a macro to redefine it as a `static_cast` invocation when in C++11 mode. I use explicit cast in my C++ backports toolkit and thus in all the C++ code I write, and I have found no important issues so far.